Power Automate - How to get the sum of multiple SharePoint currency Columns
We recently did a Migration from On-Prem to Online, and this includes 6 Currency columns.  5 manually entered Actuals, and 1 Total Actuals column.  The Values for the Total Actuals column did not migrate successfully for some reason.  So I'm trying to build a manual flow to calculate the sum of those 5 Columns, and populate the Total Actuals column with that Sum.  I can't seem to find a solution to this specific issue, so any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you

If you just want to achieve the sum through flow, it is recommended that you use Calculated column, which is more convenient:
Create a Calculated column and fill in the following formula in the Formula section:
=Column1+Column2+Column3+Column4+Column5

This is my test:

This is the result:

Good day!
